# int i vs int index etc. Which one is better?

Tags: variables, coding-style, iterator, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is a variable named i unacceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130775/is-a-variable-named-i-unacceptable) 
>   [What is an ideal variable naming convention for loop variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101070/what-is-an-ideal-variable-naming-convention-for-loop-variables)

Coming from a C background I've always used `int i` for generic loop variables. Of course in big nested loops or other complex things I may use a descriptive name but which one had you rather see?

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<Controls.Count;i++){
  DoStuff(Controls[i]);
}
```

or

```
int index;
for(index=0;index<Controls.Count;index++){
  DoStuff(Controls[index]);
}
```

In the current project I am working on there are both of these styles and index being replaced by `ndx`.

Which one is better? Is the `i` variable too generic? Also what about the other C style names? `i, j, k` Should all of these be replaced by actual descriptive variables?

Comment: Is ndx really any more descriptive than i or index?  Or was it just a compromise on the number of characters to type?  ;)

Comment: I think `ind` is more straightforward than `ndx`, even though it's just the same number of characters.

Comment: @Tuzo don't ask me. One guy is a Delphi programmer so maybe it's more normal there? I believe I've seen both `idx` and `ndx` used though.

Comment: I hate `ind` -- one guy I worked with used it all the time, but sometimes it meant 'index' while other times it meant 'indicator'. Indicators were sometimes boolean (flags), sometimes integers (but not necessarily an index of anything). His poor practices have forever made 'ind' ambiguous to me. I'd use plain `i` for simple things, iteration loops etc., or `somethingIndex` for more complex things where the index might not necessarily be simply increasing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130775/is-a-variable-named-i-unacceptable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101070/what-is-an-ideal-variable-naming-convention-for-loop-variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`i`, however, is pretty standard in terms of the first loop, followed by `j` for an inner loop and `k` for an inner-inner loop, and so on.

As with almost all naming rules, as long as it is standard within a project, and works well for all members thereof, then it's fine.

Comment: I don't know about the "and so on" bit. Going to four levels probably warrants a rethink of the design. Plus, `l` is a terrible name for a variable in any context (a kind of natural barrier :-).

Comment: @Marcelo: Of course. I actually start loops with `k` and proceed to `m` and `n`, I've never needed a fourth :P

Comment: not if you matrixes are column major.  In linear algebra world m and n are pretty much standard for dimensions, not to running variables (which are i,j,k)

Answer (score 8):

When possible, I'd favor descriptive names, since we should be striving for readable code.

For temporary variables that are used in a tight code block, a short variable name is acceptable.

But if the loop or code block is very long, it is better to have a longer descriptive variable name, if for no other reason than it will make doing text searches for it easier.

Comment: `i` is a standard index variable that should be recognizable in pretty much any loop structure.

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing nested loops to access multi-dimensional array elements, descriptive iterator names are a must to create self-commenting code.
eg.,

```
for(int i=0;i<someMax;i++){ 
  for(int j=0;j<someOtherMax;j++){ 
    DoStuff(someArray[i,j]); 
  }
}
```

vs.

```
for(int row=0;row<someMax;row++){ 
  for(int column=0;column<someOtherMax;column++){ 
    DoStuff(someArray[row,column]); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like `row,column` ?

Comment: pseudocode follows any convention you wish - switching it to a comma just because.

Comment: what if you have three-dimensional array or three nested loops (matrix matrix multiply)?  I think i,j,k is as descriptive as you can be

Comment: @aaa, it's true in some situations, but in most situations I think descriptive nested iterator names can be chosen.

Comment: `r,c` is best of both worlds, imho. pretty much self-explanatory, but short and sweet.

Answer (score 4):

**Short variable names are great**, but they should have small scopes.  And they should honor the conventions of the language.  Until the day I day, my Haskell and ML code will have function-valued variables `f`, `g`, and `h` and monadic computations `m`, variables of unnknown type `a` and `b`, and lists of unknown element types `as` and `bs`.  But the scopes of these variables will be limited to short functions or `where` clauses.

My C code will have variables called `i`, `j`, `p`, `q`, `s`, and `t`.  But the scopes of these variables will be confined to individual loops (all praise C99 and the C++ backports!) or short functions.  Whether it's a loop index or another variable, **something that appears in a large scope gets a longer name.**

Answer (score 3):

I use single-letter variables as counters a lot.
Here is how I loop, exhaustively use the letters in the alphabet:

```
for (int i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i ++) {
  for (int j = 0, m = array[i].length; j < m; j ++) {
    for (int k = 0, n = array[i][j].length; k < n; k ++) {
      for (int o = 0, p = array[i][j][k].length; o < p; o ++) {
        for (int q = 0, r = array[i][j][k][o].length; q < r; q ++) {
          for (int s = 0, t = array[i][j][k][o][q].length; s < t; s ++) {
            for (int u = 0, v = array[i][j][k][o][q][s].length; u < v; u ++) {
              for (int w = 0, x = array[i][j][k][o][q][s][u].length; w < x; w ++) {
                for (int y = 0, z = array[i][j][k][o][q][s][u][w].length; y < z; y ++) {
                  f(array[i][j][k][o][q][s][u][w][y]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome +1.. now if that would've been `array[country][state][county][town][street][building][house][residents][0][name]`, I would've been stumped.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that that l, m, n, p, r, t, v, and x suck as loop variables.

Comment: looks like perl in a good shape.

Comment: I worked on a piece of code where they used a,r,s,e as vars. It spelled out a[r][s] = e in the inner loop. Still not sure if that was on purpose.

Comment: MY EYES OH GODMYEYESWHYARETHEYBURNING THE GOGGLES THEY DO NOTHING

Answer (score 3):

The scope of an item's visibility should dictate how descriptive that name *needs* to be.

If you literally have a tiny loop, i, j, and k are fine and typical index counters.  Sometimes a more descriptive name can help illuminate intent, but if the for loop is set up like the following, then a more descriptive name doesn't really matter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; ++i)
{
   Thing& myThing = things[i];

   // do stuff with myThing, never refer to i again
}
```

That said, *abbreviations* should never be used unless they're used consistently.  I personally think `ndx` is a terrible identifier because it's hard to type; I can type English perfectly well and my programming speed is not limited by my typing speed.  If you want to say `index` say `index`.

I believe that it was in The Pragmatic Programmer that they said you shouldn't use abbreviations because then people will never know what abbreviation to use.  I know I want a thing called `index` so I type `index` but I get a compiler error.  Now what?  (Hunt through the code to find that it's written `ndx` will bother me.)

As I try to think about it, about the only abbreviation that I use that isn't game specific is 'num' to stand in for 'numberOf'.  Other than that I use 'npc' to mean non-player character, 'ai' to mean artificial intelligence, etc., etc., and sometimes I use abbreviations in small blocks, e.g. a 10-line function operating on a Camera may just call it 'cam', but the scope is small so it's easy to see what's going on and the possibility for confusion is limited.

So- small scope -> do whatever you like (as long as there's some consistency).  Large scope -> make your names unambiguous, meaningful, and easy to type.  (By "easy to type" I mean "easy to remember how to spell" as well as "don't go overboard".)

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to naming, it's all about clarity. I'd say most people who look at code know that "int i" is some sort of index, but they probably assume it's a plain old vanilla usage. So if it does something clever (ie not just simple counting up), you should call it something that makes this fact clear.

Answer (score 1):

If it is small block, and there are no nested for loops, i is just fine, it's almost as unwritten rule that i is a loop incremental variable whenever it appears. In everything more complex, good naming is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use i,j however instead of loop variables I tend to try and use **for each** when the language allows it - I find that even better.

Comment: Yes of course, but this is both relating to my coding in C and C# and possibly even a bit of Ruby

Comment: +1 .. if indexes are not needed and the language supports collection iteration, I prefer it even if it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use `x` and `y` for instances when I am parsing some 2-dimensional object like a bitmap.

```
for (int (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        // work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never use single-letter variable names for one simple reason -- have you ever tried to search for all occurrences of a certain variable in a file, or across multiple files?  It's better to use something a little less ambiguous and more searchable.

Comment: If your single-letter identifiers are always scoped tightly, then it's meaningless to search for all occurrences of them.  :)