# What does the variable i in for loops stand for?

Tags: loops

Having trouble understanding what this variable is and where it gets defined:

```
for i in range (0, 5):
    print i
```

Prints out number 0 - 4 like expected, but I don't understand what `i` means.

Comment: You couldn't check the documentation on loops?

Comment: it is usually preferred over `for hamsandwiches in range(0,5)` because some people find it quicker to type

Comment: "where it gets defined" depends on what programming language this is.

Comment: I don't know what's worse, this question for the mere fact that no research appears to have been done to answer such a trivial question or the fact that a member with a reputation over 117K attempted to answer it.

Comment: Interesting: Same question has 72 upvotes over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101070/what-is-an-ideal-variable-naming-convention-for-loop-variables?lq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886320/int-i-vs-int-index-etc-which-one-is-better?lq=1

Comment: @Thilo in other StackExchange communities they give more upvotes... facts.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a variable that assumes the values of the elements of an iterable object.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is just a name chosen for the variable that holds the current array index in each loop iteration.

This is not hard coded, you can choose any name you want:

```
 for someOtherName in range (0, 5):
    print someOtherName
```

`i` is very traditional, probably comes from "index".

If you are iterating over something other than an integer index, or think your program could benefit from a more context-bearing name (such as in nested or very complex loops), you should probably give it a different name.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is just a variable which takes values in the range. It could have been named anything within the rule defined by programming language-grammar.

This variable `i` is supposed to take values in the range 0 to 5 in the given code.

So, i will iterate from 0 to 4.

5 is exclusive from i as we're talking about range function which excludes the right-bound(right hand side limit).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, its just a local variable. You could call it just about anything you wanted and use that name in your loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you have nested for loops the second one usually uses j as its variable and for loops, in general, can be visualized to be iterating through vectors or matrices (if nested), it could be a reference to linear algebra, where there are I and J to represent the two axes as the basis vectors.

Answer (score -1):

For me, `i` = iteration. That's how I grab it.

Answer (score -1):

From my Knowledge, It comes from FORTRAN, where variables starting with "i"
through "n" were integers.

This is how our developers started using "i" as a standard loop counter over 60 years ago

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).