# Strange Bubble sort behaviour

Tags: c, bubble-sort

Can anyone explain why this bubble sort function doesn't work and why I lose numbers in my output? I'm very new to C, so please forgive me if this is something very obvious I have missed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bubble(int array[],int length) {
  int i, j;
  int temp;

  for(i = 0; i < (length); ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < (length - 1); ++j) {
      if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        temp = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int array[] = {12,234,3452,5643,0};
  int i;
  int length;

  length = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
  printf("Size of array = %d\n", length);
  bubble(array, length);
  for (i = 0; i < (length); ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Size of array = 5
12
234
3452
0
0
```

Comment: This is the best question I've seen here today - upvoted. But telling you what the problem is would spoil the fun that is programming. Think how clever you will feel when you sort (no pun intended) it out for yourself.

Comment: As part of learning C, you will want to learn how to use the debugger.  The debugger will allow you to step through your sort function one line at a time and examine the array after each step.

Comment: You might like to read my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101070/what-is-an-ideal-variable-naming-convention-for-loop-variables/101239#101239 for why `i` and `j` can be unhelpful names for variables in nested loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < (length-1); ++i) {
  for (j = 0; j < (length-i-1); ++j) {
    if(array[j] > array[j+1]) {
      temp = array[j+1];
      array[j+1] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

In a bubble sort you only use the inner loop variable.

Answer (score 4):

In your inner loop, you don't use j at all. Double check your logic.
Also note that array[i+1] goes beyond the array boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing, the inner loop goes from `0` to `i` if I remember well; but I think that's just an optimisation (as the tail is remains sorted in each step).

Try to run step by step your code with paper and pencil. That always works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < (length); i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < (length-i); j++) {
    if(array[j-1] > array[j]) {
      temp = array[j-1];
      array[j-1] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```